# Can not seem to ignore dependency in roll up

Tags: reactjs, webpack, rollup

I've got some horrendous code that has to be added to our project that you can see below. It basically checks if react-router exists in webpack and then tells our component what environment it is on.

```
  let Link;
  /* eslint-disable -- We have to use __non_webpack_require__ to handle the case when consumer has no react router (which is our external dependency) */
  try {
    // Link = __non_webpack_require__ && __non_webpack_require__('react-router/lib/Link');
    if (__non_webpack_require__) {
      Link = __non_webpack_require__('react-router/lib/Link'); // for Webpack
    } else {
      // Below line causes issue
      Link = import('react-router/lib/Link').then(module => module); // for Rollup
    }
  } catch (e) { }
  /* eslint-enable */
```

So how my project is setup is this is a repo that is a small part of a bigger one where react-router exists and we don't want to install react-router on our side as it causes other bugs. Because of this I get the below error when I go to build the bundle from rollup.

[image]

I've tried to ignore the dependency by using the skip property, the 'rollup-plugin-ignore' dependecy and also the externals property in webpack and none of these seem to work.

Examples:

```
skip: ['react-router/lib/Link'], // Default: []
```

```
  externals: {
    ...nodeExternals(),
    'react-router': 'react-router',
  },
```

and following the example given here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-ignore